# Why am I getting this error using if statement in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Here is my code for the LoginServlet class.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    boolean loginFailed;

    User user = null;

    user = loginService.getUser(userName);

    if(user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)){

        userType = loginService.getUserType(user).getUser_type();

        if(userType.equals(USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER)){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
            response.sendRedirect("home_customer.jsp");
        }else{

        }
    }else{
        loginFailed = true;

        request.setAttribute("username", userName);
        request.setAttribute("loginFailed", loginFailed);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

I have boolean named loginFailed. It will be give a value true when the user does not have an account. I made a code in my jsp page to check this variable. Here is my jsp code.

```
<body>
<div class="container container-table" id="login">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div style="background-color: #297f56; padding: 15px; border-radius: 5%;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center; color: white;">JJ STORE</h1>
                <% Boolean loginFailed = (Boolean) request.getAttribute("loginFailed");
                   if(loginFailed){
                       out.println("<div class='alert alert-warning'>Warning! Dont submit this.</div>");
                   }%>
                <form action="processLogin" method="post">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="email" style="color: white;">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  value="${username}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd" style="color: white;">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. I tried changing the condition in the if block by putting "true" and code went smoothly. However, if I put the boolean I got from the servlet, it gives me this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS5yl.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only setting `loginFailed` when it fails. When it succeeds, you're not setting the attribute, so you're getting a null value in the JSP, resulting in a `NullPointerException` when you call `if(loginFailed)`.

One way to fix the problem is to test the `Boolean` object without unboxing:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(loginFailed))
```

Another option is to make sure to set the attribute whether it succeeds or fails:

```
if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
    //...
    loginFailed = false;
} else {
    //...
    loginFailed = true;
}
request.setAttribute("loginFailed", loginFailed);
```

Comment: Your first suggestion fixed my problem! Its my first time encountering that. I'm a trainee jr software engineer by the way and one of the projects given to me was to create websites the primitive way (using servlets and jsp). I don't understand why I have to use Boolean instead of boolean (I got this from another answer here). Anyway, thanks buddy!